# How to accessing the SCORM package from s3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, drupal-8, scorm-cloud-api

Successfully able to upload the SCORM  package zip and unzip in S3 bucket using drupal 8.
While trying to read the SCORM files in the extracted data folder we got the error message like

"ERROR – unable to acquire LMS API, content may not play properly and results may not be recorded. Please contact technical support"

I checked the access stuff all are in public only

Can anyone tell me where i missed

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CiKYR.png)

Answer (score 0):

That content sounds like its setup to look for the API or API_1484_11 (SCORM API's for 1.2 and 2004) and pop up an alert.

With a runtime API present that alert would go away.  Your next question - "How do I expose a runtime API?" the answer is normally you hand roll one, or look for a Runtime API paid or otherwise.

Something like https://github.com/cybercussion/SCOBot/blob/master/QUnit-Tests/js/scorm/SCOBot_API_1484_11.js might get you started if your looking for free.

If you plan to build a LMS you may want to look into paid options.